# MathJax does not work on question title on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, title, mathjax

[image: broken MathJax]

Although, the question is displayed correctly with MathJax when opened.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Spreadtrum
- Device Model: Celkon A35K

  - OS Version: 4.4.2 (eng.root.20140613.225402)